# How to perform an onClick event with text only link

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I make simple text excecute some onClick code? I have tried Hyperlink but onClick doesn't work with that. The only way I can do an onclick is in a button like this..

```
<asp:Button ID="btnInbox" runat="server" Text="InBox" onclick="BtnInBox_Click" />

Protected Sub btnInBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    pnlMainPhoneMenu.visible=false
    pnlNewMessage.visible=false
    pnlInbox.visible=true
End Sub
```

But I don't want it to look like a button.. I don't want the button box, I just want plain text that can be clicked on.
I am using Asp.Net and VB.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [LinkButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnInbox" runat="server" Text="Inbox" />

Protected Sub btnInbox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInbox.Click
  pnlMainPhoneMenu.Visible = False
  pnlNewMessage.Visible = False
  pnlInbox.Visible = True
End Sub
```

---

For anyone new to this:

- `<asp:Button />` Renders as `<input type="submit"/>`
- `<asp:HyperLink />` Renders as `<a href="#"/>`
- `<asp:LinkButton />` Renders as `<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('','')" />`

Comment: Thank you.. Never used LinkButton before, I'm just learning. Big help thank you so much.

Comment: Always happy to help out a fellow developer.